# unzip files from dropbox on linux server

Tags: zip, dropbox

I try to unzip a .zip file on my linux server that was downloaded from dropdox, but it does not work. Any idea what causes the problem?

```
unzip -Z myfile.zip


Archive:  myfile.zip
[myfile.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of myfile.zip or
          myfile.zip, and cannot find myfile.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: This sounds like the file was not downloaded completely (most likely) or is corrupted otherwise.

Comment: Please add the output of `file myfile.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to be corrupt, but `zip` can fix it:

From `man zip`:

> -F
> --fix
> -FF
> --fixfix
>
> Fix the zip archive. The -F option can be used if some portions of the archive are missing, but requires a reasonably intact central directory.  The input archive is scanned as usual, but zip will ignore some problems.  The resulting archive should be valid, but any inconsistent entries will be left out.
>
> When doubled as in -FF, the archive is scanned from the beginning and zip scans for special signatures to identify the limits between the archive members. The single -F is more reliable if the archive is not too much damaged, so try this option first.

so, you may use

```
zip -F myfile.zip -O myfile_fixed.zip
```

or

```
zip -FF myfile.zip -O myfile_fixed.zip
```